# How to load certain scripts only on single pages of custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

This following fails to load the scripts in the single pages,

```
if(is_single( ) ) add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_js');
```

Suppose, If i use

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_js');
```

the action is performed and scripts are loaded.

I need to perform the action only on single pages of a custom post type. How to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is you have to check for the single page into the function:

```
function build_js(){
    if( is_single() && get_post_type()=='CustomPostTypeName' ){
        wp_enqueue_script(....);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_js');
```

instead of

```
if(is_single( ) ) add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_js');
```

Comment: Can you please explain why? 
Why should an action be performed un necessarily? Why is_single() fails in the first place?

Comment: @JaganK I am not sure but as i know this is because of action_hooks, my guess is all these hooks and filters initiating before rendering entire page.

Comment: You can also "pre register" de script using `wp_register_script` and enqueue when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the logic further with the Wordpress function `is_singular()` instead.

```
function build_js(){
  if( is_singular('CustomPostTypeName') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script(....);
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_js');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could include the value of [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) in your condition.

```
if(is_single() && get_post_type()=='CustomPostTypeName' )
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_js');
```